# Does Adobe PDF iFilter 11 use the same GUID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, pdf

Plenty of instructions exist for installing the Adobe 9 PDF iFilter to allow SharePoint to crawl PDFs.  I've done this, but my crawls are *sloooow*.  I'm wondering if the v11 iFilter would be faster, but not finding any instructions referencing this.  Does it use the same GUID in the registry key, or is it different?  Is there any benefit or drawback to using the latest iFilter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe PDF iFilter 11 installation instructions: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/Acrobat_Reader_IFilter_configuration.pdf

It's using the same GUID as previous versions: `{E8978DA6-047F-4E3D-9C78-CDBE46041603}`

I doubt it will greatly improve the crawl performance. I'd rather take a look at the Foxit PDF iFilter (http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter)

Answer (score 1):

After installing Adobe PDF iFilter 11 on SharePoint 2010, we experienced a 7 fold improvement in full scans on our largest content source from 18.5 hours to 2.5 hours. As I understand it, the v. 11 filter has multi-threading enabled, whereas the v.9 filer was running serially. Several "experts" told me that the filter version was not the problem for slowness, but our experience seems otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steven, plus PDF indexing is built into SharePoint 2013 through Format Handlers. Previewing is too, without a plugin if you use OWA. You cannot replace the out of the box format handlers with a third party either.

Comment: How has SP2013's PDF crawl performance been?  I'm seeing .5 docs per second with Adobe's iFilter in 2010

Comment: Which is why I use Foxit in SharePoint 2010. Fixit is significantly faster and better built than Adobe. The performance is much better across the board for all file types that use the file handlers. I haven't done any head to head tests myself, but do notice the difference. Add to that the previews from OWA for PDF, its a no brainer.

Comment: I've considered that, but we're going to 2013 soon and from what I'm reading it's not supported in 2013?

Comment: Not supported? Do you mean not needed?

Comment: No, I just read that you couldn't override the OOB iFilters in 2013.  It was on the internet, so it must be true.

Comment: That is correct, for the built in File Handlers, you cannot override them, but you can write a call-out to augment the search results. (Not that you should, but you can.)